# SQL update multiple rows based on multiple where conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `Dossiers` table with a `print_flag` column and i want set `print_flag`=1 for multiple rows.

```
UPDATE dossiers SET print_flag = 1 
WHERE id=1013997,id=1020799,id=1020800,id=1020800;
```

How should the SQL look like?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the IN clause as it'll allow you to use multiple values for a single column.

```
UPDATE dossiers SET print_flag = 1 
WHERE id IN(1013997, 1020799, 1020800);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `IN` clause as:

```
UPDATE dossiers 
SET print_flag = 1 
WHERE id IN (1013997,1020799,1020800,1020800);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE dossiers 
SET print_flag = 1 
WHERE id IN(1013997,1020799,1020800,1020800);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the IN clause.
(BTW, i dont think the double of 1020800 is necessary, so i've omitted it.)

```
   UPDATE dossiers SET print_flag = 1 
   WHERE id IN(1013997, 1020799, 1020800);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure about the ids you are passing in the query are existed in table than you may try this one :

```
    UPDATE dossiers SET print_flag = 1 WHERE id IN (1013997,1020799,1020800,1020800);
```